# git p4 submit without manual intervention

Tags: git-p4

I am trying to have automation to integrate changes from git to p4 but when I finally execute "git p4 submit", I a seeing VI editor popup with details about p4 client, files modified, commit messages etc.. (i don't want to change anything from popup, Just quitting without change) and after it is asking for confirmation to type "yes" before submitting which is stopping me from moving forward in automation,

Any idea on how to make git p4 submit happen without manual intervention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following option will do what you are looking for:

```
git-p4.skipSubmitEdit
```

This and other options are described in `git p4 --help`.

Comment: Thanks Vitor, It worked after executing "git config git-p4.skipSubmitEdit true" inside folder

Answer (score 0):

When I understand right you want to get rid of vi edit window.
Simply use eg

`-m "some text"`

or

`--no-edit`